# Undeclared Throwable Exception when using Spring Boot AOP controller advice with join points matching jpa repository functions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop

**Problem:**

- Spring boot service using MVCS architecture. I am using Spring AOP advice (around advice) for all functions present in any class in repository directory. So for example when jpa save method is called, the around advice is triggered.
- Now, Here is how things get called when no exception occurs.

  - `CONTROLLER` -> `SERVICE LAYER` -> `call to repository layer function triggers advice function which allows join point to proceed` -> `REPOSITORY LAYER` -> `around advice` -> and everything executes fine.
- Now, Here is the flow when exception is thrown by the controller advice function.

  - `CONTROLLER` -> `SERVICE LAYER` -> `call to repository layer function triggers advice function which allows join point to proceed` -> `REPOSITORY LAYER` -> `some DB exception occurs (for example trying to set a database attribute with NON NULL constraint to NULL)` -> `back to controller advice, it catches the exception then throws a custom checked exception to service layer and than going through service layer and then controller where the exception is handled`.
- The problem is that service layer doesn't know about controller advice (it acts like a proxy) and thinks that repository layer won't throw any exception since it doesn't declare `throws` in its methods signature (for example the default save method).
- So the exception that reaches the controller is not the one which is thrown by the controller advice functions. In fact Java wraps that exception inside UndeclaredThrowableException.
- One way to deal with this situation is to check ex.getCause() and get the exception which java wrapped in UndeclaredThrowableException.
- Another is to declare `throws` in the repository methods signature so that the service layers can know about the repository function throwing exception. (But this is not possible for default implementation provided by jpa - like the save function - atleast not without overriding the save function) and this I don't want to do because there are a lot of jpa inbuilt functions to override.

Any elegant solution/suggestion to the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot magically violate JVM restrictions about throwing undeclared checked exceptions. Therefore, you will have to

- throw a checked exception which has actually been declared in the intercepted target method, or
- throw a runtime exception instead, optionally wrapping it around the checked exception you want to throw.

Sorry, I cannot change the JVM for you. You need to play by its rules.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem actually by declaring exception at service layer instead of repository layer and providing the service layer's path in point cut expression.